# Linear interpolation in Keras

Tags: python, keras, interpolation

How can I add a linear interpolation layer in Keras?

I have hourglass network ("channel_first"), and at some point in decoder part I have to do a linear interpolation from size (32,128,152) to (32,128,256) after my relu layer.

I tried conv2DTranspose and Upsampling2D none of which allow fractional upsampling rate. Reshape and Imageresize also did not work. (my input is not an image it's a raw data matrix size 64*2462)

Comment: Image resize is exactly an interpolation of 2D data: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.image.resize`, as it is interpolation of 2D data. There are several kinds of interpolations possible, including "bilinear", "bicubic", etc.: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize

In order to work around the problem of channels first, you can simply reorder your dimensions:

```
model.add(Permute((2,3,1))) #brings the channels to the last position
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.resize(x, size)))

#if you wish to go back to channels first:
model.add(Permute((3,1,2)))
```

To be honest, Keras favors the usage of channels last in its functions (axes are usually assumed to be -1, certain activations and losses will go for axis -1, etc.)

I'd use channels last, no doubt. Even if I kept the data channels first but added `Permute` as the first layer of the model. But that's a personal preference, of course.